# Get all values that are exclusively in one category

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below schema.

```
MovieInfo (mvID, title, rating, year, length, studio)
DirectorInfo(directorID, firstname, lastname)
DirectInfo(mvID*, directorID*)
GenreInfo(mvID*, genre)
```

I am looking to output a list of details of actors who have worked in 1 genre only eg Action movies. Movies to Genre is a one to many relationship.

I have this so far but am getting errors.

```
SELECT ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname
FROM ActorInfo, GenreInfo, CastInfo
WHERE CastInfo.mvID = GenreInfo.mvID
AND CastInfo.ActorID = ActorInfo.ActorID
AND Genreinfo.genre = 'ACtion'
MINUS
(SELECT ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname,
FROM ActorInfo, GenreInfo, CastInfo
WHERE CastInfo.mvID = GenreInfo.mvID
AND CastInfo.ActorID = ActorInfo.ActorID
AND Genreinfo.genre != 'Action')
GROUP BY ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname,
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you lack COUNT(*) in the SELECT list of the second query. Also, why is the second query in parentheses? Why is the GROUP BY clause outside the query?

The problem is that in the first query you have `ACtion` string, instead of `Action` - that's not the same.

Try this:

```
SELECT ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname
  FROM ActorInfo, GenreInfo, CastInfo
WHERE CastInfo.mvID = GenreInfo.mvID
  AND CastInfo.ActorID = ActorInfo.ActorID
  AND Genreinfo.genre = 'Action'
MINUS
SELECT ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname
  FROM ActorInfo, GenreInfo, CastInfo
WHERE CastInfo.mvID = GenreInfo.mvID
  AND CastInfo.ActorID = ActorInfo.ActorID
  AND Genreinfo.genre != 'Action'
GROUP BY ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname;
```

Comment: Sorry i've edited the Querey I had in my question. I pasted the wrong one from my workings, count is not necessary. If i take out the count it returns no results.

Comment: @user2873893 Check my edited answer. The problem is, I guess, that you had `ACtion` string instead of `Action`.

Comment: yep, i adjusted that. It's still returning an empty table. seems as though the query's are cancelling each other out.

Comment: Are there any Actors who have played only in Action movies in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this way:

```
select
        ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname, max(genre)
from
        ActorInfo,
        GenreInfo,
        CastInfo
where
        CastInfo.ActorID = ActorInfo.ActorID and
        CastInfo.mvID = GenreInfo.mvID
group by 
        ActorInfo.ActorID, ActorInfo.firstname, ActorInfo.lastname
having
        count(distinct genre) =1 and
        max(genre) = 'Action'
```

Comment: Sorry i've edited the Querey I had in my question. I pasted the wrong one from my workings, count is not necessary. I'm looking for actors who have only worked in one genre.

Comment: You can remove the max() from the end, if you need only the unique genre actors list. This is what you mean?

Comment: still need to specify the genre what the genre is. lets say 'action'. so need all actors who have acted only in action movies.

Comment: I added a max(genre) to the select. It should give you the expected result.